# flutter Error launching application on iPhone 11

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-m1

I can't run my application its show me this type of error.

[image]

Comment: have you already installed android on your mac?

Comment: yes, i installed

Comment: Then run flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: have you also add the sdk of cmd command line? in android studio were it can be installed in sdk manager

Comment: productdesigner@Leads-Mac-mini agros_shipper_10_jan % flutter doctor --android-licenses 
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.

Comment: i just want to run this, in ios emulator

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following stuffs :

from terminal run following commands :

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `cd ios`
4. `pod install`
5. `pod update`

now you can try to install on iphone simulator.

Comment: I've done all that but still getting the same error

Comment: Failed to package
    /Users/productdesigner/Documents/ios_shipper/agros_shipper_10_jan.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Ok, do one more thing.  open xcode -> open preferences -> goto locations -> derived data -> move to bin and empty the bin  and then follow same steps again.

Comment: I've done that, but still having the same error

Answer (score 0):

First of all install the "android sdk command-line-too as shown in the below image.
You can install it by checking the check box then click on the install/apply button which will be shown on bottom right corner.

[image]

Then accept the Android studio licenses by running the following command in the command line tool (cmd) then accept all the licenses by entering -> y and enter.

->flutter doctor --android-licenses

Then let me know the issue is solved or not?

Comment: still same, please help me

Comment: Failed to package /Users/productdesigner/Documents/ios_shipper/agros_shipper_10_jan.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Can you descriv exact error for ios